# Force removing items from Trash

Tags: macos, terminal, trash, catalina

I deleted a user folder from Macintosh HD/Users that was inactive. It is now in the Trash and when I attempt to empty trash or delete immediately I am unable.

I used Terminal to navigate to:

```
cd ~/.Trash
```

then attempted the following three options:

```
rm -R name_of_folder
rm -rf name_of_folder
sudo rm -rf name_of_folder
```

None of these worked. Getting errors such as "not an empty directory" or "file is in use."

When I show invisible files in Finder using Shift + Command + . I can see that the user folder I deleted has an invisible "Library" folder inside with various subfolders inside of that.

I do not believe any of these files or folders are being used by the system as they are currently in the trash and no longer in the "Users" folder on my Macintosh HD.

How do I remove these files?

(I am running macOS Catalina public beta 8)

Comment: I have had success with an app called “Trash It”...

Comment: if you right click on the trash file I think you get an option to force delete. You get force delete someway but i'm not sure how. Force quit has worked for me but is maybe one of the command line commands you've tried.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please click on the [tag:trash] and you'd see a lot of questions asking almost the same question. Also have a quick look at the [tour]. (notify me by @ankii).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Different. This is something I encounter a lot. You should try these tricks from the finder. You can open the trash and ctrl-click the file you want to delete and select delete immediately. You can also try holdind down the option key while emptying trash.  These methods were recommended by [this reference](https://www.imore.com/how-force-empty-trash-your-mac-using-terminal), I don't know the corresponding terminal command if there is one.